# CSS absolute positioning elements inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `.wall` `div` with a some `.toy` `div`s inside it. I want to arrange the [`toy`s inside the `wall`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcfAq.jpg). `float:left` property has done it for me nicely.

Now the problem is I want to add `position:absolute` for the `toy` divs to make it draggable later. How can I do this either via Javascript or via CSS?

Applying `position:absolute`, all `toy`s will come to the top left corner of the `wall` overlying and hiding each other.

The width and height of the `wall` is constant but the width and height of the `toy`s is variable, also the number of `toy` divs is dynamic and as the number increases [`toy`s need to arrange as rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfcdK.jpg).

Any suggessions will be helpful, please note the I can not avoid the use of `position:absolute` for dragging.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
 <style>
  body{
   text-align:center;
  }
 .clearfix{
  clear:both;
 }
  .wall {
   border: 5px solid #cde;
  margin:auto;
  width:200px;
  padding:10px;
  }
 .toy{
  background-color: #BBCCEE;
  border:1px solid #8899BB;
  margin:5px;
  width: auto;
  padding:5px;
  float:left;
 }
 .tall{
  padding-top:10px;
 }
 </style>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toy').each(function(index) {
   var position = $(this).offset();
   var prevPosition = $(this).prev().offset();
   $(this).css({
    //top: position.top,
    //left:position.left,
    //position:'absolute',
   });
  });
 });
 </script>
<div class='wall'>
 <div class='toy'>T1</div>
 <div class='toy'>T2</div>
 <div class='toy'>T3333333</div>
 <div class='toy'>T4</div>
 <div class='toy'>T5</div>
 <div class='toy tall'>T6</div>
 <div class='toy'>T7</div>
 <div class='toy'>T8</div>
 <div class='clearfix'></div>
</div>
```

[Here is the code at JSBin](http://jsbin.com/idixe/edit).

Comment: The ***wall*** needs to have position relative, not the toys.  There seems to be a miscommunication below.  The *container* element needs position relative for position absolute to work on the *contents*.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, *wall* need to have position relative and the *toys* need to have position absolute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>I am working on a website that does exactly that (sorry for the non-english stuff):</strike>

http://moveit.canassa.com/cartao/4/

The link is now broken but here is a jsFiddle that shows what I am talking about:

http://jsfiddle.net/canassa/Z9N3L/

The "toy" div is using a position absolute:

```
.toy{
    width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

The problem with the position absolute is that the toy will be relative to page and not the "wall" container, in order to fix that you must make the wall container relative:

```
#wall{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The overflow:hidden is also a nice trick that I found. It makes the draggable objects go "under" the wall container.

There is no big secret to make it draggable, using jQuery:

```
// Creates a toy div inside the wall
$(MV.wallId).append('<div class="toy" id="' + this.getId() + '"></div>');

box = this.getBox(); // return the "toy" that I've just created.
$('#' + this.getId()).draggable();  // make it draggable
```

Comment: This is what i exactly want, would be great if you could show me some code snippets

Comment: Edited the post in order to include the Javascript part

Comment: The link to the example is now broken.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank Thanks for pointing it out, I've written this ages ago. I've updated it with a jsFiddle

Answer (score 4):

Add

```
position:relative
```

To the wall div

Answer (score 1):

This would be a lot easier if you just used the jQueryUI `.draggable()`. It doesn't require the elements to be positioned.

If you're dead set on using this plugin, then you have the right idea. Let the elements flow into place and then calculate their position and set `position: absolute` and whatever the `left` and `top` end up being at runtime.

Set the `.wall` to be `position: relative`. Then:

```
var tPos;

$('.toy').each(function(index) {
    tPos = $(this).position();
    $(this).css({
        left: tPos.left,
        top: tPos.top
    });
};
$('.toy').css({
    position: absolute
});
```

The height of the `.wall` and the width of each `.toy` collapse when the toys are absolutely positioned but you can just add a few more lines to get/set their width and height in the above `.each` loops.

This obviously doesn't work if new toys can be added dynamically without a page reload as you suggest. To handle that you could switch them back to `position: relative`, add the new one, get the position of the new one in the flow, then set the position and switch back to `position: absolute`. Any elements that had been dragged out of place would be gaps in the flow, but I don't see any easy way around that.

Comment: setting the left, top, and postion:absolute has no effect, see the output here http://goo.gl/60r1

Comment: Can you post the code to jsbin.com so I can see your implementation? All I can see from the screenshot is that it isn't working, not why.

Comment: Ahh, if you insert `alert(position.top + ' ' + position.left);` before you change the CSS you'll see what's going on. When the previous element gets `position: absolute` it reflows the page so the current element now takes the position of the previous one. As a result they all get the same position. I'm updating my example to one that works, you seem to be on the right path already with the second `.each()` you commented out.

Answer (score 0):

the element in that the absolute should be positioned, must have the style position:relative.
(must be a parent of the target element)

Comment: Please understand that I'm using plug in http://plugins.jquery.com/project/drag for DnD, so `toy` divs must have set `position:absolute`

Answer (score 0):

The container `div` for every `.toy` must have `position:relative` set. That way, the position 0 for its children elements becomes its top left corner. Like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Blah.</div>
    <div class="child">Blah.</div>
</div>
```

And:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px; /* This is 10 pixels from the parents left side */
  top: 10px; /* This is 10 pixels from the parents top side */
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: This will arrange all the child elements 10 pixels from the parents left side 0 pixels from the parents top side overlaping one on the top of another

Comment: @Mithun P: Yes, they will. I was just trying to illustrate my example. By the way, I think you mean "10 pixels from the parent's top side".